# Super slow rendering in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera

Why it renders so slow?

https://jsfiddle.net/g3xf5hyy/

In IEa and Firefox it works super fast.

```
  .xxx {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #333;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }





<div>


  <div>

    <div>

      <div class="xxx">
very-long-line-without-any-line-breaks-thousands-of-chars
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its an interesting problem and i will definitely try to find the root cause.
Its slow due to below css in your class

```
     word-break: break-all;
```

Remove it from your CSS and it will work fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/g3xf5hyy/2/

Comment: I can make this very StackOverflow page slow in Chrome 57 (but not Firefox 47) by using a bookmarklet to inject the rule `* { column-count: 1 !important; }` this results in the keyboard Page Up and Page Down keys becoming considerably unresponsive (although mouse wheel is OK), and I reproduced it only on this StackOverflow page (in its April 2017 format). I discovered this while trying to work around an annoyance in recent versions of Chrome when my [stylesheets for low vision](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/ssb22/css/) are used with it. My impression of Google is they don't listen to bug reports.